# Edges not beveling evenly / correctly

Tags: modeling

I tried applying the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale* but it did nothing. How do I get the edges to bevel evenly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work on your Pre Beveled mesh, or undo the bevel.
You have double vertices in three of your corners. (remember I'm talking about the unbeveled mesh.)

Select everything (<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and *[Remove doubles](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#remove-doubles)* found in the tool shelf or from the specials menu <kbd>W</kbd>.

Then in edge select mode you can reselect the top edge with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd>, and use the bevel tool.