# Bevel issue (noob question)

Tags: modeling

Why i cant bevel this corner properly. I thought i should apply scale but it doesn't help.[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46953/edges-not-beveling-evenly-correctly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12288/why-are-the-longer-edges-being-beveled-more

Comment: Oh thanks. Merge by distance helped.